# Do we need a programming tag here?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does this site need a programming tag?  It certainly doesn't give me much clue about what to expect the question to contain.

UPDATE:  I'm retagging these questions, but need help, they are coming in faster than I can retag them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This tag needs to be killed and blacklisted with extreme prejudice.

There are 122 questions tagged with [programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming): *every* question is about programming.

What's even worse is that there are questions that are *only* tagged [programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming). There really shouldn't be a tag that's solely there so you can avoid putting useful tags for your question.

Comment: Agreed.  I'll retag some, trusting you will do the same.

Comment: To be fair, not *every* question is about programming. Some questions can be about law, freelancing, business concerns, or other subjects relevant to programmers. We're a *Programmers* SE site, not *Programming*.