# What is the `great-programmer` tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across the tag [great-programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/great-programmer). What does this even mean? Is this a garbage tag that should just be removed?

---

For anyone working on the tag clean-up, please watch out for a few things:

If it's a question that should be closed, don't retag - flag or vote. If it's closed and can't be saved, flag for deletion. If it's a good question, try to make as many edits at the same time as possible (consider the title, body, any other tag changes, and answers).
Just don't flood the homepage with a bunch of minor edits to questions. It just buries new questions.

If you aren't sure if you can save a question, feel free to discuss it somewhere - in this question or in chat. If an edit is going to be made, make it a good one.

Just generally reduce the number of edits to a single question as well as the number of questions you edit at a given moment in time. Thanks!

Comment: It adds no value and should be nuked.

Comment: I think the tag is used for questions about great programmers, or becoming a great programmer :p

Comment: Little did you know that Alexander the Great was a programmer, let alone that he has his own tag

Comment: @Rachel I would hope that every question on this site is about becoming a great programmer :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just tried to +1 my own question because of your edit lol

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a terrible tag and it should die an ignoble death.

We had it on [the chopping block](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1940/8) before, but it slipped through the cracks while we were dealing with even worse tags that were far more prolific.

Kill it. Kill it with fire.

Comment: How do you really feel about it Mark?? :)

Comment: Well let's get to untagging!

Answer (score 6):

It's amazing how when investigating crap tags like [great-programmers], you always discover other equally (or more) crappy tags. This time I found [passion] and [career-advice]. Oh, well, all three were cleaned up, and will be removed from the system automatically.

Unfortunately some [great-programmers] questions from the good old days were unsalvageable *and* without any lasting value, so they went the way of the dodo.