# Blacklist [programming] and [programmers]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist

Other sites have been able to get their site name and primary focus blacklisted:

- [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/625/how-about-getting-rid-of-the-english-tag)
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/why-wordpress-tag-on-wordpress-answers)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/block-the-cms-tag)

This is a request to get ours blacklisted as well.

Our entire site could be tagged with [programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) and/or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmers), and people tend to use it as a tag when they don't have anything better to tag their question. And, like other zero-content tags, it tends to attract a large number of questions that were never good fits for our site anyway.

Previous discussions:

- [Tag consolidation and blacklist](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/tag-consolidation-and-blacklist)
- [Do we need a programming tag here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/543/do-we-need-a-programming-tag-here)
- [Yet another cleanup idea](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/yet-another-cleanup-idea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this was silently completed at some point. Hooray!

Answer (score 10):

Go for it. I agree, having the main focus as a tag doesn't make sense.